# Changing background image once using either CSS or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been asked by a friend to set up a web page whose background changes only once when any of the links are clicked. I've tried a few examples given on this site and looked at a few on Google, but they are pretty much all gallery-style cyclical changes. Perhaps I'm just frustrated and not seeing the trees for the forest...

The page is @ mysite/julie
The images are @ mysite/julie/images/blogbka.png and /images/blogbk.png

I used the solution found below ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/11362465/1506620 )

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: So for a given visitor, you want them to see a background when they arrive and a different one if they click a link.  If they come back in an hour, or a day, should they revert back to seeing the original, or is the change meant to be (near) permanent?  Or am I missing the point - should they change happen as they click the link, and when they arrive at the destination page, they see the original background again?

Comment: The former, yes. When the page loads (at whatever time) it has one image, and whenever a link is clicked it changes for the duration of the visit.

Comment: I see you are a Dr. Who fan... I can respect that... However not showing us what you tried and making us visit your page and surf through your code.... I cannot. Please update and show us in the question what you have tried miss Pond.

Comment: I have tried both of the solutions below, and both work. I will be using Random's code. Will update my post to reflect this. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var is=true;
document.body.onclick = function( e ) {
    if ( e.target.tagName === 'A' ) {
if(is){
document.body.style.background='url(http://adultdave.co.uk/julie/images/blogbka.png)';is=false;}
}
};
```

Comment: `querySelectorAll`, What about older browsers ?

Comment: site is using mootools, so thats ok

Comment: Excellent! Thank you so very much. Great stuff, Random.

Comment: Okies... The awe gets even more some.

Comment: Don't forget to click on the check mark at the left side of answer

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you want, i.e change image only once. If not, do tell me.

```
var ischange=true;
document.onclick=function(e){
if( e.target.tagName === 'A' &&ischange)
{
document.body.style.background='url(/*Image url*/)';
ischange=false;
}
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vy37j/5/)**

Here on each page load a variable ischange is initialized true, and when any link is clicked, the background is changed and ischange is set to false, so that no more background changes are allowed.

Comment: Nice, will give this one a go too.

Comment: @AshwinSingh you can't use '=' in if condition and e.target is also wrong

Comment: @Random Thanks, I think its tagName. Am I right?

Comment: and also use capital a because the tags are capitalized

Comment: Thanks buddy, had long not used them. @user1506620, changed a bug and attached a DEMO, have a look at the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use a function that wraps another function, only performing the inner function the first time its called.  This is a fairly generic version of such:

```
var once = function(fn, thisObj) {
    var called = false;
    var val;
    return function() {
        if (called) {return val;}
        called = true;
        val = fn.apply(thisObj || null, arguments);
        return val;
    };
};
```

Then you can wrap your MooTools event listener inside a call to `once()` and know that it will only be called one time.  This can be a rather elegant solution to such problems.

Answer (score 0):

I have done bins for changing page background randomly on click of each link using jQuery.
So, please follow the steps:

1)  Include Latest Jquery java script file on header.

2) HTML:

```
 <div>
  <p>
    When you click on following paragraph link, every time it will be changed random background of the page
  </p>

  <p>
    You have a present that was really memorable. It could have been given for an 
    <a href="#">
      important occasion
    </a>
    or just for no reason at all. Tell us about the present and why it was memorable. Include the reason it was given, a 
    <a href="#">
      description
    </a>
    of it, and how you felt when you got it.

    The objective is to write a 
    <a href="#">
      narrative essay
    </a>
    about this present you were given

    The subject is a 
    <a href="#">
      memorable present
    </a>
    The three main subtopics are:
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          the reason it was given
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          a description of it and
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          how you felt when you got it
        </a>
      </li>
  </ul>
</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
  background:url("http://www.freeppt.net/background/modern-pink-floral-backgrounds-for-powerpoint.jpg");
}
```

JQuery:

```
var items = new Array();
items[0] = "http://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/10000/nahled/abstract-orange-background-29541280675430Trj9.jpg";
items[1] = "http://www.psdgraphics.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/red-flowing-background.jpg";
items[2] = "http://www.dvd-ppt-slideshow.com/images/ppt-background/background-3.jpg";
items[3] = "http://www.purplebackgrounds.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/purple-heart-background-680x544.jpg";
items[4] = "http://www.freeppt.net/background/beautiful-on-green-backgrounds-for-powerpoint.jpg";

$(function() {
    var bg_img = '',
        last_bg = '';
    $("a").click(function() {
        bg_img = items[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)];
        if (last_bg == bg_img) bg_img = items[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)];
        last_bg = bg_img;
        $("body").css('backgroundImage', 'url(' + bg_img + ')');
    });
});
```

Try DEMO on http://codebins.com/codes/home/4ldqpbc

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, you'll want to provide the user's browser a cookie to chew on and track the click event(s) for all anchor tags on the page. You could do something like:

**Mock Html**

```
<ul id="ActionLinks">
    <li><a href="#" class="tracked-click">Click Me!</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="action-clear-cookie">Clear Cookie!</a></li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Array to store options 
    var settings = {
        getRadomImage: function () {
            //Update this with your different images.
            var items = [
                "http://adultdave.co.uk/julie/images/blogbka.png",
                "http://adultdave.co.uk/julie/images/blogbka.png",
                "http://adultdave.co.uk/julie/images/blogbka.png", 
            ];
            var img = items[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)];
            return img;
        },
        cookieName: "tracker",
        cookieOpts: { expires: 1} //cookie plug-in options
    }

    //Capture all tracked clicks
    $(".tracked-click").click(function (e) {
        //Check to see if there is a cookie for the user.
        if ($.cookie(settings.cookieName) != "true") {
            var img = document.createElement('img');
            img.src = settings.getRadomImage();
            //Load up the new image and show it once it's loaded.
            img.onload = function () {
                //Fade out the body and fade back 
                /*
                $("body").fadeOut(function() {
                $(this).css({ 'background-image': 'url(' + img.src + ')' }).fadeIn(4000);
                });
                */
                $("body").css({ 'background-image': 'url(' + img.src + ')' });

            };
            //Set the cookie for the client for tracking.
            $.cookie(settings.cookieName, true);
        }
    });

        //Action for clearing cookie.
        $(".action-clear-cookie").click(function () {
            $.cookie(settings.cookieName, null)
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Code References**

- https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Answer (score -1):

Set up a jQuery script :

```
$("a").click(function(evt) {
  $('body').css("background-image", "url(/myimage.jpg)");
}
```

If you want it to change between the pages, use a session cookie (i used "simpler" functions, see (this)[http://jquery-howto.blogspot.fr/2010/09/jquery-cookies-getsetdelete-plugin.html] for instance) :

```
if (getCookie('isAlreadyVisited') == 1) {
   $('body').css("background-image", "url(/myimage.jpg)");
}
setCookie('isAlreadyVisited', 1);
```

You can also handle this by setting the cookie on the server side and add a class to your body, which changes the background (you won't have Flash of Unstyles Content this way).

```
body {
   background-image: url(img1.jpg);
}

body.visited {
   background-image: url(img2.jpg);
}
```

Comment: tats like saying doSomething();

Comment: Sorry i thought your problem was to get the event, not change the background. I updated the answer.